# Add style to html.dropdownlist when using javascript function on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to add background color to this drop down.. how can I do this.. I tried adding new{style="background-color: #fff;"}   to the below code..   but this does not seem to working..

```
     <%=Html.DropDownList("dd", 
                       new List<SelectListItem>
         {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="dd1", Value = "dd1" }, 
            new SelectListItem{ Text="dd2", Value = "dd2" }

         }
                            , new { onchange = "jsfunc()" } 


         )%>
```

I tried:

```
     <%=Html.DropDownList("dd", 
                       new List<SelectListItem>
         {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="dd1", Value = "dd1" }, 
            new SelectListItem{ Text="dd2", Value = "dd2" }

         }
                            , new { onchange = "jsfunc()" }
                            , new {style="background-color: #fff;"}


         )%>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using inline styles.  I suggest creating a class and the syntax would be

`new { @class = "yourclass", @onchange = "jsfunc()" }`

Comment: This does not work.. I replaced my last line of code with yours and it does not seem to recognize the fourth argument for html.dropdownlist..

Comment: This is likely because you have ` , new { onchange = "jsfunc()" }  `  

try
` new { @onchange = "jsfunc()", @class = "yourclass" } `

However, I suggest that you use external javascript as Null mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a syntax error, `new {@style = "background-color: #fff"}`, but you should use a class instead.

Edit

```
new { @onchange = "jsfunc()", @style = "background-color: #fff"}
```

Comment: problem is it does not seem to recognize the fourth argument for html.dropdownlist.. even if I use class instead of style.. I get error.

Comment: See my edit, does that resolve it?  You can pass one or more attributes.

Comment: This does not change the background color immediately. I have to click on the drop down to see the color? why is that

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML?

Comment: <h1><select id="dd" name="dd" onchange="jsfunc()" style="background-color: gray"><option value="dd1">dd1</option>

<option value="dd2">dd2</option>

</select></h1>

Comment: Add the first code snippet i posted to the selectlistitems.  That will change the bg of the options.  That will apply it to the options which may be what you are looking for.

Comment: new SelectListItem{ Text="dd2", Value = "dd2", @style = "..." } you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, but please note that that will change the color of all of the options (so when you are selecting, they will all be gray).  If you just want the one selected to be gray you will need to right some JS to do that.